# When to use the 'sanitize' method in view files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, security, sanitize

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and I would like to know when I *MAY*, *SHOULD* and *MUST* use the [`sanitize(...)`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize) method for **security** reasons.

An usage example can be:

```
sanitize(flash[:notice])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use it whenever you are displaying data which as been input by the user, i.e. it cannot be trusted.

For example in a chat application a user can write posts which are then displayed on the page. In this case it is important to sanitize the input.

If you don't sanitize the input, the user can inject HTML and Javascript code into your page, which affects all other users viewing the same page. This way the attacker can gain complete control over the page.

On the other hand it is not necessary to sanitize data your application created, i.e. in your example (`sanitize(flash[:notice])`) is not necessary. (Assuming you are using `flash` to display status messages created by your application)

Comment: @DR If I do not use the sanitize method for data that a user (maybe malicious) has entered, what can happen?

Comment: @Backo: `<script>i_can_haz_your_identity()</script>` can happen.